# Paypal - Get the order identifier out of transaction identifier

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I could not find info in the documentation on how to grab an order id out of the capture id that I receive from the daily transaction detail report. The only way I found was to check the links field in the capture after the capture gets the request, however, that does not seem like the best way to do it.

> Does anyone know how to achieve it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Orders V2 API, the Order ID is only used during checkout approval. It is not persisted after transaction creation, and looking up captured payment details with the transaction/capture id: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get , will not return the Order ID used during checkout, since it is not useful for anything at that point.